# Vue 3 - Typescript - Object is possibly null issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I checked other threads but couldn't find the solution.

```
setup() {
  const processingData = ref(null)
}
```

Function:

```
function create() {
  let field = JSON.parse(processingData.value.fields)

  for (let i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Error on JSON.parse(processingData.value.fields): `Object is possibly 'null'.Vetur(2531) const processingData: Ref<null>`

processingData is 100% accessable, as It's being set with another function already.

Comment: the `create` function, is it defined inside setup() ?

Comment: try printing `processingData.value` in the first line inside `create` function and check if that contains attribute called fields?

Comment: Yes, the function is inside setup(). If I console.log(processingData.value). It provides an Object, with set: fields. So should work. But as it is TypeScript in my opinion, it is standard null. No idea how to handle this error.

Comment: As you are saying you did see an Object with set: fields, did you see any value for the fields?

Comment: Yes, I see value. It's JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Typescript there is a [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) you can add to let your code know that the value won't be null when your using it:

```
let field = JSON.parse(processingData.value!.fields)
```

This should help. But as I see your processingData has no type. This will lead to another problem. TS can't find the property fields. So either parse it as any or add the type to your ref.

ref type:

```
setup() {
  const processingData: Ref<{ fields: any }> = ref({fields: null})
}
...
let field = JSON.parse(processingData.value!.fields)
```

or parse it as any like:

```
let field = JSON.parse((processingData.value as any).fields)
```

Otherwise you can logically make sure that the value is not null.

```
if(processingData.value){
  field = JSON.parse(processingData.value.fields) 
}
```